# PHP - JSON_ENCODE Number converted to string. How to fix it?

Tags: php, json

I have the following variable with some coordinates from google maps:

```
$coordinates = '(22.2819939, 114.15444100000002)';
```

So to separate them I did the following:

```
$coor = explode(',',str_replace(array('(',')'),'',$coordinates));
```

Now I need to send this coordinates to an API in the following format:

```
$message = array("location"=>array($coor[1],$coor[0]));
```

I must send this in json so I encode the array but I am getting the coordinates as strings and not as number:

```
$toSend = json_encode($message);
result-> {"location":["114.15444100000002","22.2819939"]}
```

How can I avoid json to take the coordinates as string and take them as number instead?

I need this result:

```
{"location":[114.15444100000002,22.2819939]}
```

Comment: How about `$message = array("location"=>array((float)$coor[1], (float)$coor[0]));` ?

Comment: hey mate, it modify the number... in $coor[1] I lost 0000002

Comment: waht happened if you use double `(double) "114.15444100000002"`

Comment: `114.15444100000002` looks incorrect. Google Maps provides 6 decimal points of precision, afaik. I think you hit a floating point precision issue before it got stored. `114.154441` is the number you want, pretty sure.

Comment: [See this post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8650/how-to-measure-the-accuracy-of-latitude-and-longitude/8674#8674) on GPS precision. 6 decimals gets you 0.11m of precision. There's no way you really want 14 decimals anyway.

Comment: hey jszobody that is true... I made a test without 0000002 and the precision difference is almost null. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to convert them from `string` to `float`. So we simply map the array with a float conversion

```
$coor = array_map('floatval', $coor);
```

Comment: hey mate is doenst work because it modified the number... i get "location":[114.154441,22.2819939]... now I dont have the string but I lost 000002 from the original number.... other idea?

Comment: And what's up with the backticks instead of quotes?

Comment: with quotes the number changes, with backticks is still get an string

Comment: I wonder why this answer is accepted. Backticks instead of quote ?

Answer (score 3):

See [JSON Predefined Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) and use the `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` option (but you will lose some precision):

```
$toSend = json_encode($message, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

> JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK (integer)
>
> Encodes numeric strings as numbers. Available since PHP 5.3.3.

Comment: OP is worrying that he will lose precision on those values.

Comment: The only way to keep the precision is to keep it a string.  How will the receiving code keep the precision?

Comment: @Raptor: OP had string `114.15444100000002` and you used number_format() to produce string `114.15444100000002`.  Unnecessary...

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the strings into numbers

```
$number = (float) "114.15444100000002";
```

Comment: please check my coment above, same problem with float before... it modify my number

Comment: It is because `float` has limited precision in PHP (See [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php)). You got 14 sig. fig.!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `number_format()` to achieve your goal. See this example below:

```
$num_str = "114.15444100000002";
$str2float = (float)$num_str;
echo 'Cast to Float: ' . $str2float . PHP_EOL;

$num_format = number_format($num_str, 14);
echo 'With number_format(): ' . $num_format . PHP_EOL;
```

The result will be:

```
Cast to Float: 114.154441
With number_format(): 114.15444100000002
```

Proven `number_format()` works in your case.

---

p.s. you should make use of this function **after** you parsed the JSON. You should leave your values in string to prevent loss of precision during encoding and decoding.

p.s. As @jszobody mentioned, if the values are really coordinates, the precision should never require to go beyond 6 decimal places.

Comment: Except, 14 decimal places in a GPS coordinate is absurd. Even _seven_ decimals gets you to millimeters of precision.